# How to identify encoding from hex values?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I have text on a website that displays like that: `o¨` instead of `ö`

I extracted the text out of the CMS and analysed it's hex values:

- the ö's that are displays correctly have `c3 b6` - UTF-8
- the ö's that are displayed incorrect have `6f cc 88`

I couldn't find out what encoding this is. What's a good way to identify the encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`6F` is the UTF-8 (ASCII) encoding of "o", nothing spectacular.
`CC 88` is the UTF-8 encoding of [U+0308, COMBINING DIAERESIS](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0308).

You're simply looking at the *decomposed* form of the o-umlaut. A combining diaereses character *should* visually be rendered, well, *combined* with the previous character. If your system doesn't do that, it means it doesn't treat Unicode correctly, and/or the font you have chosen is somewhat broken. Perhaps you have to [*normalise*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) your strings into the composed Unicode form instead for your system to handle it correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Well, my system is the browser (current version if Firefox, IE - I think in Chrome it worked, not sure anymore). The font in use is a Google Font - so I doubt there's a problem with either the system or the font. // Actually it seems to be the font that is the problem, I found that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19706263/603569