# How to fix the display of German's umlauts in firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

Firefox incorrectly displays characters with umlauts.
Dots are not drawn above the letter or drawn but not there (near).

We using custom font: OpenSans
In Chrome everything is fine.
There are no problems in Linux Firefox either.

May be it is just firefox bug?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704167/special-chars-issue-in-firefox-and-ie-using-webfonts-with-utf8

Comment: Yes, thank for link. Problem the same.

Answer (score 0):

answer:

Problem the same as there 
[special chars issue in firefox and IE using webfonts with utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704167/special-chars-issue-in-firefox-and-ie-using-webfonts-with-utf8)

Question closed

Answer (score -1):

You can use HTML codes for special characters. The code for ë is &euml ; <- put the ; 
 directly after the code. If you use PHP you can do str_replace to replace them. 
Otherwise you need to do it yourself. Search for HTML UTF-8 characters and you will 
see all the options :)

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the HTML contains `&euml;` or a literal `ë`. The same letter should end up in the DOM.